# issue with js dropdown sub menu items positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a web designer and new in stackoverflow, I have this issue with positioning drop-down menu links (more specifically aligning them to the left of the menu) because there is a space between the menu left border and the beginning of the links (check the live demo link below). I've tried text-align, float, margin, padding, and position properties but none of them seem to solve this. I think that the menu css might be conflicting with other css code of the page, but I just can't seem to find it.

You can check the source code from a [live demo of the page here](http://codetest.uphero.com/).

Comment: Your demo page isn't working.

Comment: there was something wrong on the server. Now it works and i still couldn't solve this. and btw i've tried your tip but.. no improvement.

Comment: Ok, now that I can see what you're talking about, I'll take a look and update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on how your code is structured, this is how I would modify your css to do what I think it is you're trying to do - I'll ** the css changes I've made:

```
.dropdown dd {
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
width: 200px;
display: none;
background: #f8f8f8;
z-index: 200;
opacity: 0;
**border-right: 1px solid #004e8e;**
}

.dropdown ul {
**overflow: hidden;**
width: 204px;
border: 1px solid #004e8e;
list-style: none;
}

.dropdown li {
**display: block;**
**position: relative;**
**left: -40px;**
}
```

This should get rid of the extra space on the left as well as put that blue border around the drop-down that I believe you were also trying to create.

Comment: Great! thanks kinakuta, that was exactly what i was struggling with. Sometimes when you work too much on something and never get it to work you need to look at it from outside, because the solution could be as easy as you can't see it from the inside :) just like in my case lol.